# How to run a SQL Query from Excel in VBA on changing a Dropdown

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a dropdown that upon changing the selection from the list of options will run a query that will insert the query results into the page.  Here's what I have thus far:

```
    Sub DropDown1_Change()
   Dim dbConnect As String
   Dim leagueCode As String
   Dim leagueList As Range
   Dim leagueVal As String

   Dim TeamData As String

    Set leagueList = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("A5:A10")
    Set leagueVal = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Cell("B1").Value

    leagueCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(leagueList, leagueVal)

    TeamData = "SELECT DISTINCT(Teams.teamID), name FROM Teams WHERE lgID = '" & leagueCode & "' & ORDER BY name ASC"

    With Worksheets("Menu Choices").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=dbConnect, Destination:=Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("D5"))
        .CommandText = TeamData
        .Name = "Team List Query"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Anywho have any suggestions to get it working?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is dbConnect? Have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178808(office.12).aspx? You should change the leagueval line to read : `leagueVal = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("B1").Value` : Set is only used with objects, not strings. Your SQL statement is also incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for catching the leagueVal issue, that was just frustration-code and I didn't catch it when I posted it up here.

dbConnect is used to pass the connection string from another function to the query.

Thanks for the link - I'll check that out tonight and see if that helps.  Just getting into this kind of functionality with VBA (and VBA in general) so your comments are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue using similar code to the following:

```
Sub createTeamList()
  Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

  Dim SQL As String

  Dim inc As Integer

  Dim topCell As Range
  Dim leagueID As String

  Dim leagueList As Range
  Dim leagueChoice As Range

  Set leagueList = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("A4:A9")
  Set leagueChoice = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("B1")

  leagueID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(leagueList, leagueChoice)

  Set topCell = Worksheets("Menu Choices").Range("D4")

  With topCell
    Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
  End With

  With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\lahman_57.mdb"
    .Provider = "Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider"
    .Open
  End With

  inc = 0

  SQL = "SELECT teamID, name " _
        & "FROM Teams " _
        & "WHERE lgID = '" & leagueID & "' " _
        & "GROUP BY teamID, name " _
        & "ORDER BY name "

  rs.Open SQL, cn

  With rs
      Do Until .EOF

         topCell.Offset(inc, 0) = .Fields("teamID")
         topCell.Offset(inc, 1) = .Fields("name")
         inc = inc + 1
         .MoveNext
      Loop
  End With

  rs.Close
  cn.Close
End Sub
```